# Find charge enclosed in the rectangular prism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, gauss-law, integration

> Consider a rectangular prism with cross section of a right angled triangle as shown. The coordinates of the vertices A, B, C, D and E are $(\sqrt2,0,0)$, $(\sqrt2,\sqrt2,0)$, $(0,\sqrt2,\sqrt2)$, $(0,0,\sqrt2)$ and $(0,\sqrt2,0)$ respectively.
>
> There exists an electric field $x\hat i+\sqrt2y\hat j+\hat k$ $N/C$ everywhere. If the charge enclosed by the prism is $(N+\sqrt N)\times\epsilon_0$ then, find the value of $N$.
>
> [image]

So, I know we have to use Gauss's law to solve this question but I am stuck at the part for finding the flux through face ABCD.

One way to solve this is writing the divergence of the given electric field vector and dividing it by the volume, but when I try to find the flux of the electric field through ABCD I am confused at what I should consider $\mathrm dS$; namely I can find out the direction of the normal by cross product and it comes out along ($i+k$) but what should I write as the differential part? I thought of writing it as $\mathrm dS= |AD|\mathrm dy$ (direction of $\mathrm dS$), but that doesn't help because then the integral of $E\cdot\mathrm dS$ would give me and $x\mathrm dy$ term which I can't figure out how to solve.

I am not asking for the complete solution or specific computation, just a hint on how to proceed with the flux through ABCD.

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: @Discord Warrior Yep it's good, I understand but my teacher posed it as a challenge to find out the flux without the use of double integral, is it possible somehow?

Comment: @SOUMILINAG Okay, I think we can do it by taking projections of ABCD onto the x-y and y-z planes and individually calculating the flux of each projection and adding them up.

Comment: @Discord Warrior I was trying it out, but wouldn't that become a little too complicated?

Comment: **Hint** :

Follow @Discord Warrior's suggestion : Express the field in components 
$$\mathbf E=\mathrm E_x\,\mathbf i+\mathrm E_y\,\mathbf j+\mathrm E_z\,\mathbf k$$
and check the fluxes component-by-component and side-by-side to realize that what  remains is to determine the (outwards) fluxes of $\,\mathrm E_y\,$ through the side BCE  (very very easy) and $\,\mathrm E_x\,$ through the side ABCD  (a little difficult) without any integration.